# Angular Reactive Form: Remove Specific Validator from Control

Tags: angular, validation, customvalidator, formgroups, angular-abstract-control

I am working with Angular reactive forms.
In my scenario, validators are added dynamically to my controls.

This is done like follows:

```js
const myControl = myFormGroup.get('myControl');

if (myControl.validator) {
    myControl.setValidators([ myControl.validator, Validators.required ]); //preserve existing validators
} else {
    myControl.setValidators([ Validators.required ]);
}
```

This works just fine.

**The Problem**

*I need a way to also remove a specific validator while preserving the others.*

`myControl.validators` only returns a function but not an array of validators which makes it impossible to pick one to remove while leaving the others.

I know there are workarounds like keeping track of the existing validators elswhere, etc.
My question however is: can this be achieved directly on the `AbstractControl`?

The following issue on Github discusses the problem:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

The solutions provided there don't seem to work for me, as I am not only having to deal with the required validator but also with numerous custom validators.

Thanks in advance for any hints or solutions to this!

Cheers, Mike

Comment: I think that keeping track of validator and clear + add all without required is the easier way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss for your evaluation of the issue. This certainly would work. But I am looking for a "clean" solution which works with the ```AbstractControl``` only, because in my code, validators are added in different locations from different sources. E.g. validators are added asynchronously based on a loaded json schema of the business object, other validators are added dynamically and custom validators are added manually on the form. So, keeping track of all these sources is practically impossible. Angular letting me down here...

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think this is a limitation of Angular that can only be solved cleanly by a change in the framework. Currently (we are on Angular 9), this has not been addressed. We have implemented a workaround (keeping track of all the validators on the controls over time and use these "snapshots" to reconfigure validation).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since there is no elegant solution to this, I have bitten the bullet to write my own RequiredIf validator.

It does two things:

- cache the original validators of the controls it is applied to. Should a property no longer be required, it will restore the original validators (while removing the required validator).
- it adds valueChange listeners on the property, the validation depends on. If a property becomes required or is no longer required, it will validate the control to immediately show the new validation results.

Here's my code of the validator (just as I use it currently, no time to optimize it).

```
import { FormGroup, ValidationErrors, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class ValidationSubscriptionCache {
    static observedPropertyCombinations = new Array<string>();
    static subscriptions = new Array<Subscription>();

    static unsubscribeAll() {
        for (let subscription of ValidationSubscriptionCache.subscriptions) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}

export function CombineProperties(property: string, otherProperty: string) {
    return `${ property }.${ otherProperty }`;
}

export class ValidatorCache {
    static cache = new Array<ValidatorsOfProperty>();

    static currentlyRequiredProperties = new Array<string>();

    static isCurrentlyRequired(property: string) {
        return ValidatorCache.currentlyRequiredProperties.indexOf(property) > -1;
    }

    static removeFromCurrentlyRequiredProperties(property: string) {
        const index = ValidatorCache.currentlyRequiredProperties.indexOf(property, 0);

        if (index > -1) {
            ValidatorCache.currentlyRequiredProperties.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    static isInCache(property: string) {
        const found = this.cache.find(x => x.property === property);

        if (found) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static addToCache(property: string, validators: any) {
        const toAdd = new ValidatorsOfProperty();
        toAdd.property = property;
        toAdd.validators = validators;

        ValidatorCache.cache.push(toAdd);
    }

    static popFromCache(property: string): ValidatorsOfProperty {
        const item = ValidatorCache.cache.find(x => x.property === property);
        const index = ValidatorCache.cache.indexOf(item, 0);
        ValidatorCache.cache.splice(index, 1);

        return item;
    }
}

export class ValidatorsOfProperty {
    property: string;
    validators: any;
}

export function ValidateRequiredIf(property: string, otherProperty: string, valueThatMakesRequired) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {

        const propertyCombination = CombineProperties(property, otherProperty);
        const otherValue = formGroup.get(otherProperty).value;

        //register changes of other property and refresh validation if it changes
        if (ValidationSubscriptionCache.observedPropertyCombinations.indexOf(propertyCombination) < 0) {
            ValidationSubscriptionCache.observedPropertyCombinations.push(propertyCombination);

            const valueChangeSubscription =
                formGroup.get(otherProperty).valueChanges
                    .subscribe(() => {
                        formGroup.get(property).markAsTouched();
                        formGroup.get(property).updateValueAndValidity();
                    });

            ValidationSubscriptionCache.subscriptions.push(valueChangeSubscription);
        }

        //set or remove the required validator based on the depending property
        const isRequired =
            otherValue !== null &&
            otherValue !== undefined &&
            otherValue.toString() === valueThatMakesRequired.toString();

        if (isRequired && !ValidatorCache.isCurrentlyRequired(property)) {
            ValidatorCache.currentlyRequiredProperties.push(property);
            ValidatorCache.addToCache(property, formGroup.get(property).validator);

            if (formGroup.get(property).validator) {
                formGroup.get(property).setValidators([ formGroup.get(property).validator, Validators.required ]);
            } else {
                formGroup.get(property).setValidators(Validators.required);
            }

        }

        if (!isRequired && ValidatorCache.isCurrentlyRequired(property)) {
            ValidatorCache.removeFromCurrentlyRequiredProperties(property);
            formGroup.get(property).setValidators(ValidatorCache.popFromCache(property).validators);
        }

        return null;
    };
}
```

And here's the application on the form:

```
this.myForm.setValidators(
                    [
                        //city is required if the country is switzerland
                        ValidateRequiredIf('city', 'nationality', 'switzerland'),
                        //[add more]
                    ]);
```

additionally, you have to call `ValidationSubscriptionCache.unsubscribeAll();` in the `ngOnDestroy()` of your component holding the form.

Cheers, Mike